# Why isn't one of my class functions being recognized in the body of main() in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a checkers game using objects, but the compiler isn't recognizing one of my class's member functions.

Here is what I've written:

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        Board b(10);
        b.displayBoard();
        return 0;
}
```

Board.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Board
{
public:
        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;
        char spaces[1000];        
        Board(int);         
        ~Board();        
        const int Area();
        //...//        
        void displayBoard(); // <- not being recognized?!
        //...//
};
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Board::Board(int s)
{
width = height = s;
//assumes spaces holds at least width*height
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (static_cast<bool>((i + j) % 2)) {
            spaces[i*width + j] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            spaces[i*width + j] = '#';
        }
    }
   }
}

Board::~Board()
{
    //delete  spaces;
}

const int Board::Area()
{
        return width * height;
}

//...//

void Board::displayBoard(void)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        cout << spaces[i*width + j];
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
 return void();
}

//...//
```

I don't know why DisplayBoard isn't being recognized in the body of main(). The error I'm receiving says "Error C2039   'displayBoard': is not a member of 'Board'" which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had duplicate files with the same name.